# Efficiently loading sitemap from database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, authentication, authorization, sitemap

i have a custom `SiteMapProvider` which I populate from a database. I also have a custom `SiteMapNode` which has to be constructed with a custom `Page` argument.

The implementation of `SiteMapProvider.IsAccessibleToUser(context, node)` is now:

```
Public Overrides Function IsAccessibleToUser(context, node) As Boolean
    Return CType(node, CustomSiteMapNode).Page.IsAccessibleToUser(context.User)
End Function
```

I also have a custom `authentication class-attribute`:

```
Public Class ValidateAuthorization : Inherits AuthorizeAttribute
    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Function AuthorizeCore(context) As Boolean
        If Not CType(SiteMap.CurrentNode, JrcSiteMapNode).Page.IsAccessibleToUser(httpContext.User) Then
            Throw New ApplicationException()
        End If

        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

---

**Two questions:**

1. **Should I return false in AuthorizeCore() to have everything work according to default authorization protocols? (What are these?) Or should I throw my exception..?**
2. SiteMap.CurrentNode is Null / Nothing (in AuthorizeCore()) if the page which is requested is not accessible to the user (obviously). **How should I change my implementation? I want to keep the functionality that the `Page` objects are only loaded once, so I need to store them somewhere...** I'm very confused / mental blocking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently have 2 sitemaps. One with, and one without security trimming enabled.